# String from Text Field

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, uitextfield

I'm trying to get the title of a String from the content of a UITextField, so you can always  edit it and save it.
I've already linked the String and the UITextField, but everything works just if you edit the content of the UITextField in the storyboard, and it doesn't work in the application (Simulator and Devices).

This is what I'd like to do:

```
const NSString *nameOfTheString = @"the content of the text field, that you can change when you want from the application"
```

Here there is the code that I have:

```
nameOfTheString = nameOfTheTextField.text;
```

I Hope You'll Help Me.

I'm using Xcode 6 (Objective-C)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change `nameOfTheString` if it is a `const` (constant). If you want to change `nameOfTheString`, simply use `NSString *nameOfTheString;` to declare it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the const from the declaration (const means it can't be changed):

```
NSString *nameOfTheString;
```

Then use a delegate method of UITextField to update the value of the string whenever it is changed:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    nameOfTheString = textField.text;
}
```

UITextField delegate ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: It doesn't work, I removed the "const" from the declaration and put the "nameOfTheString = textField.text" in "textFieldDidEndEditing", but nothing works, it's always the same. Maybe it'a saving and loading problem?

Comment: Make sure that you have set the delegate of that TextField to the ViewController that owns it.

Comment: I'm going crazy, I'm trying to do it for months. This thing is blocking the publication of my application! :(

Comment: Zip up your project or at least the ViewController and post on GitHub and send me a link.

Comment: Ok, now I try to do something about it

Comment: In ViewController.h "UITextField *TextField;" and "-(IBAction)saveDataOfMyTextField:(id)sender;" In the next comment I'll send you the .m file.

Comment: In ViewController.m: "-(IBAction)saveDataOfMyTextField:(id)sender {
    NSString *saveString = TextField.text; NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"savedString"]; [defaults synchronize];" and "String = TextField.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"savedString"]; [TextField setText:loadString];"

Comment: This is just the part of the project about my question

Comment: Use the delegate method I outlined in my answer.  There is usually no good reason to use an `IBAction` event to respond to `UITextField` events.  Implement the delegate method and in the Storyboard, select that `UITextField` and the under the connections inspector, drag from the delegate connection to the ViewController.

Comment: But when I remove "nameOfTheString = TextField.text" delegate method from "viewDidLoad" and put it in "TextFieldDidEndEditing" the UITextField works just like a normal one, just like a text, with no functions. Another thing, if I have to remove the IBAction event, which one should I put to replace it? Anyway, thank you for the great help you're giving me.